# TextImageRelationship is not working as expected in contextmenustrip - VB

Tags: vb.net, contextmenustrip

Is it possible to align image above text in `contextmenustrip` item in vb?

It is always Image being left of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `ContextMenuStrip` called `TextImageRelation`
and set it to`ImageAboveText`